# Update values from layer one to layer two where there is no identical ID but identical geometry

Tags: qgis, network

I have one huge problem and that is to get the value from one layer into another. It is a network with over a million links and I need to update a table from a layer of + 100 000 links. I am using QGIS and tried intersect, overlap on smaller data but I don't get the result I want. The two layers have identical geometry but one layer for example can have one long link compare to layer two that can have several links (road intersections) so overlap and intersection does not work. I did try the "Select by location" and "Include input features completely within the selection features" It did work as I wanted but when trying on the bigger data it just sit there for many hours (or overnight) and I don't know if it is working or just freezed in the process. All I want is to match the data and update the values from one layer to the other. As there is no identical ID I can not use the "Join" function but have to use geometry match instead. Is there another way around this problem?

Comment: What are you updating?  Just attributes, just geometry, or both?  Which is the target layer?  The one with the longer geometry or the one with the intersected geometry?  If the target is the longer geometry, what do you want to occur if two features that join to it have different attributes?  Anyway, I would probably Spatial Join and keep only features that touch to limit the set of possible feature matches, then use a dictionary to store the join features and an update cursor to process the target features by Spatial Join IDs, compare the geometry, and make the updates where there is a match.

Comment: I am updating attributes only, target is the one with the intersected geometry so there will not be two features and both layers are shape files.

Comment: I'd compute shorter dataset midpoints first. Spatial join points to long features, nearest. This might take long with 1 mil features. Points will get attributes of both sets. Count number of points (summarise) per long feature ID, remove ones with frequency=1. Remaining points = bridge between 2 sets

Comment: Any idea how to compute the midpoints for polylines? No python experience here for me and did not find any plugin neither...

Comment: If you want to transfer attributes from one layer to another layer, when line segments are identical, my answer to a [network related question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151634/merge-lines-while-adding-attributes-spatially/151669#151669) may be helpful. Instead of adding attribut values you would do an assignment. Afterwards you have to dissolve the segments based on an unique attribute of the target layer. To customize the script some more details about your data structures are necessary.

Comment: @Detlev, not sure what you mean but of course interested for an solution as I am lost at the moment. Shapefiles are the same geometry with no "mismatch" except that they have different length of geometry. Its a road network with few attributes like shape length and dates, it has the intersected geometry.

Comment: I want to get for example the street names into this layer and the "street name layer" has long geometry so it gets difficult to "assign" this to each intersected geometry without getting errors by using the SQL "intersect" as it picks all other roads that are connected, then I need to assign other values as well from several shape files with similar geometry. Does this help? Thanks

Comment: @QGIS-user, the idea is, that Networkx while creating a network can assign attributes from different sources to common edges. Since all incoming lines are splitted into segments, segments shared by different sources (your layers 1 and 2) own different sets of attributes. As a result you can export the network with a new set of attributes from both sources, say the ID from layer 1 and the street names of layer 2, and then dissolve the segments to form longer lines. Tomorrow I will provide my attempt of a solution as answer based on this method.

Comment: Just for clarifications, I need the "master" file to continue be splitted into segments (no change in original) or it will not work in the next process after I have assigned the attributes I needed (street names, speedlimits, etc) Thanks

Comment: @QGIS-user: thanks for the test dataset. I have improved my answer so it fits exactly your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Given 6 layers the Python code executed in Python console (or executed from the editor) attributes will be transfered to features from layer 1. Layer 1 contains the features which provide the master geometry. They must be equal to, contained by, or disjoint from geometries of features in the other layers.

Layer 1 (differentiation of roads by number of lanes; attribute: *Lanes*; identified by feature id); in this example the *master geometry*

[image: Layer 1: differentiation of roads by number of lanes]

Layer 2 ( (differentiation by street name; attribute: *street_name*)

[image: differentiation by street name]

And so on.

Now the Python code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
import datetime
print 'Starting at: ', datetime.datetime.now()

# get layers; one line for each layer to evaluate, with layer1 containing the master geometry
layer1 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('thtn-vbg')[0]
layer2 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('thtn-vbg_funk')[0]
layer3 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('thtn-vbg_speed')[0]
layer4 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('thtn-vbg_street_name')[0]
layer5 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('thtn-vbg_one_way')[0]
layer6 = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('thtn-vbg_urban')[0]

# specify for each layer the attribute to transfer to the master geometry
attributes_dict = {layer2: 'KLASS', layer3: 'HTHAST', layer4: 'NAMN', layer5: 'RIKTNING', layer6: 'RLID'}

# split lines into segments and save all segments into a dict along with provided attributes
# master geometry; must be equal to, contained by, or disjoint from other geometries
segments = {}
for line in layer1.getFeatures():
    c = 1
    for i in range(len(line.geometry().asPolyline())-1):
        segments[((line.geometry().asPolyline()[i][0], line.geometry().asPolyline()[i][1]),
                        (line.geometry().asPolyline()[i+1][0], line.geometry().asPolyline()[i+1][1]))] = {'fid': line.id(), 'seq': c}
        c += 1

# other geometries with attributes
for the_layer, the_attrib in attributes_dict.items():
    for line in the_layer.getFeatures():
        for i in range(len(line.geometry().asPolyline())-1):
            key = ((line.geometry().asPolyline()[i][0], line.geometry().asPolyline()[i][1]),
                       (line.geometry().asPolyline()[i+1][0], line.geometry().asPolyline()[i+1][1]))
            if key in segments:
                segments[key][the_attrib] = line.attribute(the_attrib)

print 'Segments built: ', datetime.datetime.now()

# prepare segments for dissolving
composed = {}
for segment in segments:
    fid = segments[segment].get('fid', None)
    if fid:
        if fid not in composed:
            composed[fid] = {}
            _attributes = [segments[segment]['fid']]
            _attributes.extend([segments[segment].get(the_attrib, None) for the_layer, the_attrib in attributes_dict.items()])
            composed[fid]['attributes'] = _attributes
            composed[fid]['vertices'] = [(segments[segment]['seq'], (segment[0][0], segment[0][1]), (segment[1][0], segment[1][1]))]
        else:
            composed[fid]['vertices'].append((segments[segment]['seq'], (segment[0][0], segment[0][1]), (segment[1][0], segment[1][1])))

print 'Segments ordered: ', datetime.datetime.now()

# define QGIS layer with attributes
layer = QgsVectorLayer('LineString?crs=EPSG:3006', 'Result', 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()
attributes = [QgsField('fid', QVariant.Int)]
attributes.extend([QgsField(the_attrib, QVariant.String) for the_layer, the_attrib in attributes_dict.items()])
attributes.append(QgsField('length', QVariant.Double))
prov.addAttributes(attributes)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# create features
feats = []
layer.startEditing()

for compose in composed:
    composed[compose]['vertices'].sort()
    feat = QgsFeature()
    vertices = [QgsPoint(composed[compose]['vertices'][0][1][0], composed[compose]['vertices'][0][1][1]), 
    QgsPoint(composed[compose]['vertices'][0][2][0], composed[compose]['vertices'][0][2][1])]
    for idx in range(1, len(composed[compose]['vertices'])):
        vertices.append(QgsPoint(composed[compose]['vertices'][idx][2][0], composed[compose]['vertices'][idx][2][1]))
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(vertices))
    composed[compose]['attributes'].append(feat.geometry().length())
    feat.setAttributes(composed[compose]['attributes'] )
    feats.append(feat)

print 'Lines built: ', datetime.datetime.now()

# finally add all created features and save edits
prov.addFeatures(feats)
layer.updateExtents()
layer.commitChanges()

print 'Finished: ', datetime.datetime.now()
```

The result is written to a memory layer, which you may save to disk. And this is the final result:

[image: final result]

Roads symbolized by number of lanes and labeled with streetname.

The script was tested with 16.000 master features, which receive attributes from 30.000 features in 5 layers. Running time was 1 minute on 3-years old PC with QGIS 2.8.2

Comment: Great! I will get back when I have tried. I will start with a smaller set first before getting into the big thing. Thanks

Comment: Seems to have problem with python, I did install networkx module..

Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
rom PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
  File "<input>", line 1
    rom PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
import networkx as nx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named networkx

Comment: `ImportError: No module named networkx` - did your networkx installation went to the Python instance installed with QGIS? If so you should have a directory like this: `d:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\networkx\`. I am not familiar with MacOS, don't know what path it has to be in your case. I suppose if the installation went somewhere else just copy the directory to the correct place. Not fine, but it works on another workstation of mine, where the same mistake happens.

Comment: I did tried on PC, I have to check on MacOS later. It worked better with no error but the Result layer is empty it has "fid", "lanes" and "Type" (one I picked, attribute that has numbers only). It seems to run fine on this smaller set… but it gives empty tables

Comment: Is it possible for you to share this small dataset, along with your code version, so I could check the process?